# Can't reach localhost in Android Studio 2 emulator

Tags: ionic-framework, android-emulator, genymotion, android-studio-2.1

I have an ionic (version 1.7) app and I can start it in the Android Studio 2 emulator. Unfortunately I can not reach my backend server at http://10.0.2.2:8181/, I always get a 404 not found error. I also tried using Genymotion (with ip http://10.0.3.2:8181/) but I still get a 404. Did anything change in the new versions or does anyone have an idea what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the URL is valid. Can you access the server in your browser?

Comment: Sorry for my late repsonse. Yeah, I can access the server in my browser just fine. I have a workaround now using ngrok to host the web server online. That seems to work in the emulators.